# Reading a file as it is written

Tags: go, file-io, real-time

Being fairly new to Go, I wrote a simple Go program that continually reads a file as it is written - for example to watch a log file for specific output, which I want to capture as soon as it has been written.

My (naive) code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fileHandle, err := os.Open("test.log")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fileReader := bufio.NewReader(fileHandle)
    line := bytes.NewBufferString("")
    for true {
        content, err := fileReader.ReadBytes('\n')
        line.Write(content)
        if err == io.EOF {
            continue
        } else {
            if line.String() == "done\r\n" {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(line.String())
            line.Reset()
        }
    }

    err = fileHandle.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

This works just fine, it prints every line of the log file as it is being written, never writing anything until it has a complete line (which is the desired behaviour).

My question: what is the idiomatic way in Go to change this code so that I can run this as a routine that blocks until there is more to read?

I know how to take the code and turn it into a go routine, but it would still be constantly trying to read the file, dealing with the `io.EOF` and continuing. Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this as a go routine that would avoid needlessly checking?

Is it a matter of constantly checking `.Buffered()` instead? Even that seems wasteful and intensive. I can slow it down with `time.Sleep()` whenever it encounters `io.EOF`, but I want to minimise the amount of delay. In Go, what is the way to wait for something to be written to the file, with a minimum of delay, and the minimum computational and I/O overhead?

(Note: I'm not asking for a rewrite of the code above, but really just an answer to the question itself, perhaps pointing at an existing example, or the appropriate functions in the documentation)

Comment: I've fallen down a bit of a rabbit hole since asking this question, since the problem gets more complicated if a file cannot be expected to eventually get a 'done' marker to show up - in such a case, a cancellable reader is required, greatly complicating things. But I'd be very thankful for useful suggestions all the same.

Comment: You'll want to use event notifications of the target platform. Linux has inotify, for instance. github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify is a popular (but now unmaintained) wrapper for several APIs.

Comment: I see, you're saying to act after the notification of a write on the file, instead of starting a blocking read until it occurs? I'd want it to be platform-independent (or at least to work equivalently on Linux and Windows), so I suppose I'd best look for the optional notification mechanism for both?

Comment: I'm late to this question as I want to do very similar things as OP and have the same doubt. Reading a file that is concurrently appended by another process reminds me the classic unix util "tail -f". So prehaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899655/how-does-tail-f-works-internally can provide some insight on what is the "classic" unix way to do this task