# How does tail -f works internally

Tags: linux, filesystems

If I run this command:

```
tail -f file.txt
```

I will see changes in real time.

My question is: How does it work ? Is there a way for a process to be notified each time a file is changed ?

Or is it a loop, like watch command do ?

Thanks

Comment: `tail` is maintained by coreutils. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tail.c#L1165).

Answer (score 2):

I too had this question, as I wanted to implement a similar feature in Java.

It looks like tail is periodically checking the size and modified date of the file against values it recorded when it last outputted the file's contents.  When it detects a change, it outputs the data at the end of the file (starting where it last left off). It then updates the values, and repeats the process.

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tail.c#L1235

There seems to be code later on to handle if the file gets truncated.

Comment: Any chance your Java code is available publicly? I'd be curious to have a look.

Answer (score -1):

With  --follow  (-f),  tail  defaults to following the file descriptor,
which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will  continue
to  track its end.  This default behavior is not desirable when you re‐
ally want to track the actual name of the file, not the file descriptor
(e.g.,  log  rotation).   Use  --follow=name in that case.  That causes
tail to track the named file in a way that accommodates  renaming,  re‐
moval and creation.

Comment: Downvoted because this is a copy and paste of the manual. If you are referring to it, it is worth quoting it properly. Also this does not answer the question.